# location of "launch configuration >> environment variables in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Anyone knows the physical location of folders/file that contain "open launch configuration" >> environment variables in tomcat set up in eclipse?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside Your workspace folder at below location.
Path:
*workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/Tomcat vX.0 Server at localhost.launch*

Answer (score 0):

CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.bat or .sh file

Comment: found no folder by CATALINA_BASE and no files by name "setenv"

Comment: setenv does not exist by default, if you need it create the user.
when tomcat starta searches for the file setenv, if it finds it it executes it otherwise it passes over and starta catalinabase.
in the file setenv you can put all the declarations of the environment variables you want to be present at the tomcat angle.

example in setenv.bat you can write:

set "name.variable=value_of_a_env_var"